# MS Access - Update a field with a date using a YES/NO field

Tags: date, ms-access

I'm a novice coder and I'm trying to create a tool using MS Access (since I can't build GUI's to safe my life) for locker management in the school I work for.

Now, I'm trying to create this feature where a student can request a locker. In my locker table, I have a column with "Wishes" which is a Yes/No field. The other column is "WishDate". This is a date field.

My idea is that if the Yes/No field is set to "Yes", the tool fills in today's date. And if the Yes/No field is set to "No", I would like that the date is emptied out (if there is anything in it) But, I'm truly stumped on how to do that. How can I build a feature like that?

The reason I would like the date field emptied if the Yes/No field is on "No", is because on the form that I created to add a student to a locker, I put the students who wanted a locker first based on that wishdate.

I hope my idea and question is clear. Otherwise, I'm willing to clarify my idea further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate date/time field based on yes/no selection, use code (macro or VBA) in checkbox AfterUpdate event. I use only VBA, so something like:

```
If Me.chkWish Then
   If IsNull(Me.tbxDate) Then Me.tbxDate = Date()
Else
   Me.tbxDate = Null
EndIf
```

Comment: Just to be sure, I need to put this in AfterUpdate event of the checkbox (YES/NO) and not the date field...? Could you give me a small rundown of how the code works? So, I understand it and get better in the future?

Comment: AfterUpdate (or possibly Change) event of checkbox. The code works just as it says. If chkWish is true then populate date field but only if it doesn't already have a value - this secondary condition may be unnecessary so if you prefer can remove it and just use `Me.tbxDate = Date()` part.

Comment: That's what I needed man! It works flawlessly. The fact that it doesn't overwrite preset dates of the users of the tool is amazing. :) Otherwise I would get a bug report for it :P